# Count of matching fields (columns)

Tags: mysql, sql

Just out of curiosity, is there a way that i can get the count of matching data in 2 or more tables.. as in,if we get the following 3 tables,

```
tbl_1-
ip  |isp    |infection
----------------------
1   |aaaa   |malware
2   |bbbb   |malware
3   |cccc   |ddos
3   |cccc   |trojan
4   |dddd   |ddos

tbl_2-
ip  |isp    |infection
----------------------
1   |aaaa   |malware
3   |cccc   |ddos
4   |dddd   |trojan
5   |eeee   |trojan
6   |ffff   |other

tbl_3-
ip  |isp    |infection
----------------------
1   |aaaa   |ddos
6   |ffff   |
2   |bbbb   |other
```

Will i be able to derive an answer like shown below??

```
Result-
ip  |isp    |infection  |Match Count
------------------------------------
1   |aaaa   |malware    |2      
1   |aaaa   |ddos       |1      
2   |bbbb   |malware    |1
2   |bbbb   |other      |1
3   |cccc   |ddos       |2
3   |cccc   |trojan     |1
4   |dddd   |ddos       |1
4   |dddd   |trojan     |1
5   |eeee   |trojan     |1
6   |ffff   |other      |1
6   |ffff   |           |1
```

Thank you :)

Comment: how did you derived the match count?

Comment: by the matching number of fields(columns) for each row :) @JohnWoo

Comment: see my answer below. `UNION ALL` is what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use `UNION ALL` (***not UNION only***)for this to allow duplicates

```
SELECT ip, isp, infection, COUNT(*)
FROM 
(
SELECT ip, isp, infection FROM tbl_1
UNION ALL
SELECT ip, isp, infection FROM tbl_2
UNION ALL
SELECT  ip, isp, infection FROM tbl_3
) x
GROUP BY ip, isp, infection
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f122e/12)

Comment: and..Thank you again for your great help :) much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

You should perform a UNION ALL of all the three tables and then run a GROUP BY by ip, isp, infection columns.

```
SELECT ip, isp, infection, COUNT(*) 'Match Count'
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM tbl_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM tbl_2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM tbl_3
) AS A
GROUP BY ip, isp, infection
```

Comment: thank you very much :) but this doesnt give the result i need..i need to count the matching number of columns per row :)

Comment: As John Woo mentioned, you should use UNION ALL to preserve duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use the COUNT() function
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but what i was confused of getting the match count of columns per row :)